# SQLAlchemy Outer Join replicating Excel's vlookup function

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I would like to replicate a Excel's VLookUp function using SQLAlchemy. For example, if I have the following two tables:

```
Department: 
 1. Sales
 2. Sales
 3. Sales
 4. Sales

Category: 
 1. Sales      Level 1
```

I would like to be able to create:

```
 1. Sales      Level 1
 2. Sales      Level 1
 3. Sales      Level 1
 4. Sales      Level 1
```

However, instead I currently get:

```
 1. Sales      Level 1
 2. Sales      None
 3. Sales      None
 4. Sales      None
```

Here is a simplified version of the script I have written:

```
data = Department.query.outerjoin(Category, Deparment.Name==Category.Name).add_columns(Category.Level).all()
```

I haven't set up column `Category.Name` as a foreign key of `Deparment.Name`

Comment: what is your tables schema?

Comment: `1.`, ..., `4.` are primary key values or a part of `Name`?

Comment: how joining by `Name` will make from `Marketing` a `Sales` record?

Comment: Please ignore 1., ..., 4. I just used them to create the table, but you can assume that there is also a separate primary key values column

Comment: Ignore Marketing that was a typing mistake

Comment: can you provide your `Department` & `Category` models definitions?

Comment: I can't - this is a simplified and made up summary of what I have

Comment: why not? it will be easier to try your example with real models instead of creating them from scratch, you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about main principles